# How to write cleaner code while instantiating an object with enumerations without using keyword?

Tags: c#, enums, namespaces

I recently created a class which has a constructor taking 3 enumerations as arguments. These enumerations are defined in the object itself as ObjectEnum and AnotherObjectEnum in the example below.

```
LongObjectName pt = new LongObjectName(
            LongObjectName.ObjectEnum.EnumerationOne,
            LongObjectName.ObjectEnum.EnumerationTwo,
            LongObjectName.AnotherObjectEnum.EnumerationThree,
            0.0);
```

I have to initialize 8 of these objects and I'd like to condense this into a clearer format for future coders. I'd like to structure this code so that I can simplify the declaration of this object - something like a "with" from VB.NET. I would have to implement the IDisposable interface in order to use the "using" command.

ideally I'd like my code to look like this:

```
LongObjectName pt = new LongObjectName( 
                ObjectEnum.EnumerationOne,
                ObjectEnum.EnumerationTwo,
                AnotherObjectEnum.EnumerationThree,
                0.0);
```

Is there any simple way to clean up code like this? 
Thanks in advance - this is my first question so constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: Why not move your enumeration to it's own file and namespace, that would achieve your goal.

Comment: @CrimsonX: You're confusing the two uses of the `using` keyword.  See my first answer.

Comment: Constructive criticism on the question itself: it's well asked; code samples are good; indication of what you've already considered as a solution is good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple way: Simply don't declare your enums within the class but in the same namespace of the class.

`using` won't help you here, by the way, as that does nothing else than wrap a `try`/`finally` around your code and call `Dispose()` in the `finally` block. It's by no means similar to VB's `With`.

**ETA:** Since you chose to accept this answer, even in the light of better ones:

You *can* use the `using` *directive* to create an alias for your enum:

```
using ObjectEnum = SomeNameSpace.LongObjectName.ObjectEnum;
```

Please give an upvote to [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650078/how-to-write-cleaner-code-while-instantiating-an-object-with-enumerations-without/1650103#1650103) and not me, since s?he was the first to come up with this idea here.

Answer (score 10):

You are confusing the two uses of the `using` keyword.

You can use the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to make an alias for any type; this has nothing to do with `IDisposable`.

For example:

```
using ObjectEnum = YourNamespace.LongObjectName.ObjectEnum;
```

(Note that all types in `using` directives must be fully qualified with the namespace name.

---

The [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) has nothing to do with the `using` directive except the name, and is used to dispose an `IDisposable`.

For example:

```
using (TransactionScope.BeginTransaction())
using (dataSet)
using (new SqlCommand("SQL", connection) {
    //Do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Constructive Critisicism

If you really want constructive criticism, run [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) on your code, or Code Analysis if you have Visual Studio Team Suite.

It will generate lots of warnings for code that violates best practices.  The warnings can be daunting for large projects, but if you approach them one set at a time, you can trim it down to a more reasonable number.  FxCop can be quite useful; it has found several bugs in my own code that would otherwise have gone unnoticed.

---

In your case, [avoid public nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx).  Unless there is a compelling reason not to, you shouldn't put those enums inside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll see if we can run this for the future and I have checked out the recommendation regarding public nested types. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Welcome to SO, CrimsonX.
2. C#'s "using" statement is not analogous to VB's "With". The "using" statement sets the scope of the object before it is disposed, but it does not initialize object properties.
3. You might consider creating static factory methods that create instances using common options, such as "Schedule.NewScheduleSevenDaysAWeek()" and "Schedule.NewScheduleWeekdaysOnly()".
4. It looks to me like you are simply trying to save keystrokes. If that is the case, Johanness' suggestion of moving the enums out of the class will help. In general, however, I think you will find C# more verbose than VB. For example, [C#'s object initializer](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/02/object-initializers-in-c-30-and-vb9.html) is intended to be a cleaner way of instantiating objects and setting properties, but it is not shorter. Cleaner != shorter.

Answer (score 1):

First things first you can do this:

```
var pt = new LongObjectName( 
                ObjectEnum.EnumerationOne,
                ObjectEnum.EnumerationTwo,
                AnotherObjectEnum.EnumerationThree,
                0.0);
```

Second, you can consider moving the enum out of the class definition or create an alias for the enum in your callers class file.

```
using ObjectEnum = LongObjectName.ObjectEnum ;
```

Comment: FYI - MSDN suggested that the var type should only be used if you are storing an anonymous type. Also, I believe your "using" doesn't work per the earlier poster's description of using (and the fact that my enumeration doesn't implement the iDisposable interface)

Comment: @CrimsonX: You're confusing the two uses of the `using` keyword.  See my first answer.